# R: extracting numbers from string

Tags: r, regex, extract

I am trying to use the package `stringi` in R for extracting number(s) from strings. The pattern of the strings is:

```
1 nomination
2 wins
1 win & 3 nominations
2 wins & 1 nomination
won 1 Oscar. Another 5 wins & 2 nominations
```

I wish to extract the number(s) in each string. If there's only **win** or **nomination**, treat the only number as the win/nominations.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
test <- "6 wins & 3 nominations."

str_extract(test, regex="\\w*\\d\\w*")
```

However, this only gives the first number, not including the second number.

`stri_extract(test, regex="\\w*\\d+wins(\\s*+&+\\s*)(\\d)")` gives NA.

The following way works, but feels too unwieldy by splitting the string first, following by stri_extract:

```
t <- strsplit(test, "&")  # split the string first
win_num <- stri_extract(t[1], regex="\\d")
nomination_num <- stri_extract(t[2], regex="\\d") # if exists
```

Any way to make the regex way work in one line? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extracting multiple numbers, use `str_extract_all` which returns a `list` output.

```
str_extract_all(test, "\\d+")[[1]]
```

Comment: it is actually `stri_extract_all(test, regex="\\d+")[[1]]`, thanks!

Comment: @TonyGW Yes, I didn't specify the `regex=`, but it works without specifying it.